# Select and count days between datetimepickers

Tags: c#, date, count, datetimepicker

I have 2 `DateTimePickers`. Between the two dates Friday and Saturday the value has to be 50 and the other value 40. It should return the total in a `TextBox`.

```
private void comBoot_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Bootid = Convert.ToInt32(comBoot.SelectedValue);

    if(Bootid ==2)
    {
        int NumberOfDays = (dtpVertrek.Value - dtpAankomst.Value).Days;
        int tekst = NumberOfDays - 1;
        txtPrijsBoot.Text = Convert.ToString(tekst*40);
    }

    if(Bootid ==1)
    {
        int NumberOfDays = (dtpVertrek.Value - dtpAankomst.Value).Days;
        int tekst = NumberOfDays - 1;
        txtPrijsBoot.Text = Convert.ToString(tekst * 75);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what isn't working? Seems like valid code to me.

Comment: Yeah - It's not really clear from your description what the exact problem is, so you might want to edit the question.

Comment: the code is working.... but it just counts days and then *40 but i want fryday and saterday to add 50 and the other days to add 40 and then display the total